# React & TailwindCSS - container element not taking 100vh when in md: screen size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, tailwind-css

so I have a swappable animated login UI that works great, but when I want it to fill 100vh in **md:** screen sizes it only fills 50vh but it fills 100vh when below **md:** size just fine. I think it might be some kind of conflict with the **react-flip-toolkit** lib, but can't find any error.

The code is still a work in progress I just wanted to solve this issue that appeared so that I can move on to finish the rest of it.

I've tried this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515195/why-100vh-is-not-taking-the-full-screen) and playing around with **min-h-screen** and other things like that but nothing solves this...

[image]
[image]

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Flipper, Flipped } from "react-flip-toolkit";

export default function Login2() {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [isLogin, setisLogin] = useState(true);


  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submitted:", { username, password });
    toast("Wow so easy!");
  };


    return (
        <div className=" relative flex font-roboto flex-col md:flex-row w-full h-screen">
        <h1 className={`absolute z-10 top-0 left-0 m-5 p-1 border-2 transition-colors delay-75 ${ isLogin ? "text-white border-white" : "text-black border-black" } font-BrunoAceSC font-extrabold text-lg`}>IOU</h1>
            <Flipper flipKey={isLogin}>
                <Flipped flipId="container">
                    <div className=" flex flex-col md:flex-row ">
                        {isLogin ? (
                            <Flipped flipId="logintext">
                                <div className=" flex flex-col bg-emerald-200 justify-center h-50vh w-full md:w-50vw md:h-screen items-center text-center ">
                                    <h1 className=" font-bold text-4xl">Hello!</h1>
                                    <p className=" text-xs font-thin pt-2 pb-5">Not Registered yet?</p>
                                    <button onClick={() => { setisLogin(!isLogin) }} className=" text-sm bg-white text-black border-2 border-orange-400 rounded-full p-2.5 px-5 duration-300 hover:ring-orange-400 hover:ring-2 hover:scale-105">Sing up</button>
                                </div>
                            </Flipped>
                        ) : (
                            <Flipped flipId="logininput">
                                
                                <form className=" flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-50vh w-full md:w-50vw md:h-screen" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center p-5 mb-2 border border-slate-300 rounded-md duration-300 focus-within:border-orange-400 focus-within:border-4">
                                        <label htmlFor="username"><i className="fa-solid fa-user pl-5  text-slate-400"></i></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Name"
                                            className="px-2 py-2 border-0 focus:outline-0"
                                            value={username}
                                            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center p-5 border border-slate-300 rounded-md duration-300 focus-within:border-orange-400 focus-within:border-4">
                                        <label htmlFor="password"><i className="fa-solid fa-lock pl-5 text-slate-400"></i></label>
                                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
                                            className="px-2 py-2 border-0 focus:outline-0"
                                            value={password}
                                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                    <button className=" text-sm bg-lime-600 rounded-full mt-5 p-5 px-16 text-white duration-300 hover:ring-lime-600 hover:scale-105 hover:ring-2">Log In</button>
                                </form>
                            </Flipped>
                        )}
                        {isLogin ? (
                            <Flipped flipId="logininput">    
                                <form className=" flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-50vh w-full md:w-50vw md:h-screen" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center p-5 mb-2 border border-slate-300 rounded-md duration-300 focus-within:border-orange-400 focus-within:border-4">
                                        <label htmlFor="username"><i className="fa-solid fa-user pl-5  text-slate-400"></i></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Name"
                                            className="px-2 py-2 border-0 focus:outline-0"
                                            value={username}
                                            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center p-5 mb-2 border border-slate-300 rounded-md duration-300 focus-within:border-orange-400 focus-within:border-4">
                                        <label htmlFor="password"><i className="fa-solid fa-lock pl-5 text-slate-400"></i></label>
                                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
                                            className="px-2 py-2 border-0 focus:outline-0"
                                            value={password}
                                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center p-5 border border-slate-300 rounded-md duration-300 focus-within:border-orange-400 focus-within:border-4">
                                        <label htmlFor="email"><i className="fa-solid fa-envelope pl-5 text-slate-400"></i></label>
                                        <input type="email" id="email" name="password" placeholder="Email"
                                            className="px-2 py-2 border-0 focus:outline-0"
                                            value={email}
                                            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                                    </div>
                                    <button className=" text-sm bg-orange-400 rounded-full mt-5 p-5 px-16 text-white duration-300 hover:ring-orange-400 hover:scale-105 hover:ring-2">Sing Up</button>
                                </form>
                            </Flipped>
                        ) : (
                            <Flipped flipId="logintext">
                                <div className=" flex flex-col bg-orange-200 justify-center h-50vh w-full md:w-50vw md:h-screen items-center text-center ">
                                    <h1 className=" font-bold text-4xl">Welcome!</h1>
                                    <p className=" text-xs font-thin pt-2 pb-5">Already Registered? </p>
                                    <button onClick={() => { setisLogin(!isLogin) }} className=" text-sm bg-white text-lime-600 border-2 border-lime-600 rounded-full p-2.5 px-5 duration-300 hover:ring-lime-600 hover:scale-105 hover:ring-2">Log In</button>
                                </div>
                            </Flipped>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </Flipped>
            </Flipper>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    theme: {
        fontFamily: {
            'roboto': ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'],
            "BrunoAceSC" : ["Bruno Ace SC", "sans-serif"]
          },
          height: {
            '50vh': '50vh',
          }, width:{
            "50vw":"50vw"
          }
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `h-screen` would not generate the rule,

```css
.h-screen {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

since you have declared your custom value in `theme.height`. This completely removes the Tailwind defaults for that property. Consider adjusting your config such that your custom value is defined at `theme.extend.height`:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      'roboto': ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'],
      "BrunoAceSC" : ["Bruno Ace SC", "sans-serif"]
    },
    extend: {
      height: {
        '50vh': '50vh',
      },
      width:{
        "50vw":"50vw"
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: damn so easy, yeah I forgot the extend. thanks a lot!